# how to Isolate Vertex Groups so they don't combine when edges collide

Tags: mesh

cube A and cube B are each in their own Vertex Group and they are separated by 1 cube length.

If I move Cube A 1 cube length closer to cube B the edges combine.

Is there any way to prevent the edges of the cubes from automatically merging when they touch?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Could you provide some screens or .blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely you have **AutoMerge** enabled in your UI. Check if this button here is clicked when you are in edit mode:

[image: automerge]

When this is on, and you move one vertex to the same location as another one (like you do in your example), the vertices are melted together. It's a feature - rarely used as far as I know - which by default is disabled.

Comment: is it enabled or disabled when it's dark grey?

Comment: nevermind :P    process of elimination....  that did seem to be the problem :) thanks (again)